# Array comparison in Google spreadshet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a script which copies the data from "Longlist" sheet to "Final" sheet (onEdit) if the data in "Longlist" sheet does not exist in the "Final" sheet.

The code below copies the data from sheet to sheet successfully however when the function runs again it copies the data even it exists in Final sheet and creates duplicate rows.

I would be glad if anybody could help.

**Note:** Google sheet does not support - data[i].equals(data2[z]) or vlookup inside script

```
function onEdit() {
    var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Longlist New");
    var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Final List");
    var data = sheet.getRange('a1:a100').getValues();  // Long List - Names
    var data2 = sheet2.getRange('c2:c50').getValues(); // Final List - Names
    for (var i=1; i<=data.length; i++)                         {
        for (var z=0; z<=data2.length; z++) {   
            if (data [i] == data2 [z]) {
                x=1;
            } 
        } 
        if (x != 1)    {   
            a= sheet2.getLastRow();
            b= sheet2.getLastColumn(); 
            sheet2.getRange(a+1,12).setValue(sheet.getRange(i+1,9).getValue());   
            ...
            ..
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var dataToCopy = data.reduce (function(a,b)   { return a.concat(b) })
                     .filter (function(e,i,a) { return this.indexOf(e) == -1 },
                        data2.reduce( function(a,b) { return a.concat(b) }))

                     .filter (function(e,i,a) { return a.indexOf(e) === i })
                     .map    (function(e,i,a) { return [e] });
```

**OBJECTIVE**

Find the elements in data that are not already present in data2.

**METHOD OF OPERATION**

1. A column array is technically an array of arrays. .reduce coupled with .concat will effectively transpose a '1D' column array into a true 1D row array.
2. .filter is used to find only the elements in data not present in data2.  data2 in this case is the thisArg of the filter function, and is represented symbolically by 'this' inside filter. Take note of the ',' at the end of the filter line. The data2 function (which is being transposed like we did to data1') is being called into the filter function there and could have been left on the same line.

   .indexOf is used to check if each element in data is present in data2, and returns -1 if the element is not present. This returns true/false for each element in data1 and filter will remove any elements that tested false. At this point dataToCopy is an array containing only the elements in data that were not found in data2.
3. This filter will remove duplicate values in dataToCopy.  indexOf returns the first index that an element is present in.  If that is not equal to the index of the current element then that element is a duplicate. This leaves us with only the unique values in dataToCopy.  This filter can be removed if duplicate values are allowed.
4. Transposing dataToCopy back to a column array. It is now ready to be sent back to the spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you for your well explained answer. However, unfortunately Object.Reduce, Filter, Concat,..() methods are not supported in Google Script

Comment: I use all of these methods regularly in my projects in google scripts. Are you using a script attached to the spreadsheet?   Did the execution transcript log an error? I tested the code snippet before posting it and everything looked good to go.